# tar.gz folder and use folder name as name for the archive

Tags: linux, tar, archiving

I have multiple folders called "runs" in my directory structure that I would like to create seperate archives of because they contain a unmanageable number of files". For this reason, I'd like to use find to find the files with that name which I've managed to do. However, upon finding them I'd like to create archives that will contain those folders and the location of the archives must be the same as the folder. I've tried the following:

```
find . -name runs -type d -exec tar -czvf {} runs.tar.gz \;
```

but to no avail. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

`runs.tar.gz` should be an option-argument just after the `-f` option of `tar`, so you need to reorder (but don't run this):

```
find . -name runs -type d -exec tar -czvf runs.tar.gz {} \;
```

This will create `runs.tar.gz` in the current working directory, you explicitly don't want this. In addition the archive will contain paths relative to `.` because `{}` expands to a path relative to the path we provided just after `find`.

---

Since the directory name (`runs`) is a substring of the archive name (`runs.tar.gz`), you may try this:

```
find . -name runs -type d -exec tar -czvf {}.tar.gz {} \;
```

There are few problems with this approach:

- [POSIX `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) may not work as expected when `{}` appears more than once;
- POSIX `find` may not work as expected when `{}` appears within a larger string (i.e. not as a separate word);
- Even if your `find` expands both `{}` as wee need, the paths in the archive will be relative to `.`.

---

Another approach:

```
find . -name runs -type d -execdir tar -czvf runs.tar.gz runs \;
```

Each `tar` will be run in the respective directory. This is probably what you want. Still `-execdir` is not required by POSIX, your `find` may not support it; but if it does support it then there should be no problem.

The last `runs` might be `{}`, it would expand with respect to the directory, in your case to `./runs` each time. If you had e.g. `find . -name 'runs*'` then `{}` would be a must.

---

POSIX solution (POSIX, when it comes to `find`; `tar` itself is not required by POSIX; `pax` is the POSIX archiver):

```
find . -name runs -type d -exec sh -c '
  cd "${1%/*}" && tar -czvf runs.tar.gz runs
' find-sh {} \;
```

Notes:

- Instead of `"${1%/*}"` it could be `"$(dirname "$1")"`. Since `find` is required to provide paths without trailing slashes, the former syntax that only manipulates strings should be OK and faster.
- In general it may be `tar -czvf "${1##*/}.tar.gz" "${1##*/}"`. In your case `${1##*/}` will always expand to `runs` but if you had e.g. `find . -name 'runs*'` then `${1##*/}` would be very useful.